# Can I reuse my sink during a kitchen renovation?

Tags: kitchens, sink, kitchen-sink

Sometime in the next few years, I'd like to redo my kitchen. But for now, I'd like to replace the beat-up double sink with a new, single sink and a garbage disposal.

If I replace the sink now, will my contractor be able to cut the sink out of the counter and reuse it when I eventually redo the kitchen? Or will I need to buy a brand-new sink if I do a renovation?

Comment: We thought the same. Last year we bought a vanity for the bathroom, thinking we'd keep it when we remodeled the bathroom. This year (now) we're remodeling the bathroom and we went on the higher end with the tile / fixtures and it just doesn't make sense to use the old vanity that a: isn't as nice as the new stuff going in and b: doesn't match well. So - completely doable if you think you'll do the remodel on a budget, but possibly plan on changing your mind later as you choose features of the new kitchen. Theres always Craigslist to sell the old stuff on.

Answer (score 5):

Most commercially purchased drop in sinks as easy to remove and reinstall.  Only custom built ins are not so easy.
Commercial drop ins are held in place by clamps up under the sink and or silicone RTV.
When removing in future the clamps are loosened and the RTV cut away.  The sink pulled and cleaned then reused.
Check the sink you plan to purchase and see how it is secured.